# C# Selenium WebElement.Click throws exception not interactable

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLZa5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKiyH.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ4SM.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLO4t.png)

When I start the program, it starts and runs fine until it goes to the point where I want the driver to click the button and it throws me the exception the web element not intractable. I've tried a lot of methods but none of them worked. The problem I think is that when this button is clicked the HTMl changes. Please help :D

---

this is the line of code that trows me the exception (C#) :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='exifInfoMobile']")).Click();
```

error : OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)'

---

and this is the HTML :

```
<li class="photo-info">
       <button class="btn btn-photo-info" id="exifInfoMobile">
               <span class="text">info</span>
       </button>
</li>
```

I've tried with WebDriverWait , By class name and by id but it didn't work. I think it has something to do with a model because when this button is clicked, the sites html changes by adding an info panel on the right. Sorry again for the bad question but its my first time asking one here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Update the question with text based HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry! Its my first time asking a question . I will try to edit the post

Answer (score 0):

If a regular .click() does not work, you can click with JavaScript.
You can use this

```
var element = sel.driver.FindElement(By.Id("exifInfoMobile"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

or this

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var element = sel.driver.FindElement(By.Id("exifInfoMobile"));
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```